# Azure mobile apps net client add new column with default value

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have already a model class called User.cs with some properties:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "admin")]
public bool Admin { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

This gives me the columns admin and email in the sqlite database.
Now I am making an update for my app. I want to add a new property and therefore a new column:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
public bool Owner { get; set; }
```

When I add this to User.cs, the sqlite file will get a new column called owner. All existing rows in the User table of the sqlite file get the value NULL for this new column.

My question: What can I do give existing rows the value 0 (false).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do, depending on requirements.  The most obvious is:

- Update the model on the server to add the Owner field,
- Update the database with a default value.
- On first run of your client (after an update), wipe the SQLite database and re-sync all data

Comment: The server has already an owner field of type bool. However an exception is thrown when the client tries to push an user with owner=NULL. Re-sync won't be possible as the first version of my app had the sync disabled, so no data on the server. Your second idea is what I am doing now. However it's not the most elegant solution. I am querying all users, and loop the result in an foreach. In the loop I call await userTable.UpdateAsync(user), so I get the value false in the table. But maybe you have a more elegant solution.

Comment: There is no "second idea" here - it's all one.  You have to do all three items.